# Fourier transform of vorticity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

For the incompressible Navier-Stokes equations: $$u_t - \Delta u + (u \cdot \Delta)u+\nabla p = 0\\\nabla \cdot u = 0$$ where $u$ is velocity field and $p$ is pressure. For vorticity $\omega=\nabla \times u$, we have the vorticity formulation:$$\omega_t -\Delta \omega + (u \cdot \nabla)\omega=(\omega \cdot \nabla)u$$

Then we know the vorticity $\omega_{ij}=\partial_i u_j - \partial_j u_i$ satisfies $$\partial_{t}\omega_{ij} -\Delta \omega_{ij} + \partial_i (u_k\omega_{kj})-\partial_j (u_k \omega_{ki})=0$$

My questions is: how to derive $\hat {\partial_i u_j}=\frac{\xi _i \xi_j}{|\xi|^2}\hat{\omega_{kj}}$ from above, where $i,j=1,2,3,...n$. We also assume Einstein summation convention.

Comment: What exactly is your question? BTW $i,j = 1,2,3,...,n$ does not make sense for the Navier-Stokes equations.

Comment: My guess: Take the Fourier transform of your formula for $w_{ij}$ and you get a linear system you need to solve for the transform of $u_j$.

Comment: @MrYouMath I've asked in my question, how to derive $\hat {\partial_i u_j}=\frac{\xi _i \xi_j}{|\xi|^2}\hat{\omega_{kj}}$

Comment: @MrYouMath For your second comment, it makes sense since $u$ is a vector-valued function, i.e. $u(x,t)=(u_{1} (x,t)),u_{2}(x,t),....,u_{n}(x,t))$

Comment: I know $u(x,t)$ is vector valued. But it does not make sense to have more than 3 dimensions in real-life flow problems.

Comment: a) Curl operator does not exist in $n$-dimensions. b) where the second index in omega may come from, since when it became a tensor?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but I write this answer for completeness. It is nothing but converting derivatives to polynomials using the Fourier transform and the fact that $u$ is divergence free.

From $\newcommand{\del}{\partial}w_{ij}=\del_i u_j - \del_j u_i$ we have $\hat w_{kj}=\xi_k \hat u_j - \xi_j \hat u_k$ up to a constant (probably $-2\pi i$). Contracting with $\xi_j$ gives $$\xi_j w_{kj} = - |\xi|^2 \hat u_k$$ since $\xi_j \hat u_j = \widehat{\nabla \cdot u}= 0$. Now multiply by $\xi_i$ and divide by $|\xi|^2$ (assuming this is legal) and the result is proven, up to a multiplicative constant which depends on convention.